# Return different messages depending on issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a jQuery Validation `addMethod` which checks a password length and ensures that the value matches another password fields value.

I can't see how to make the `addMethod` return a custom message depending on the cause, is it possible?

The two password fields are:

```
<input type="password" class="required" name="Password" id="Password">
<input type="password" class="required" name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword">
```

The code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("arePasswordsValid", function(value, element) {

    this.isValid = true;
    this.errorMessage = "";
    this.options = {
         minLength: 6,
         maxLength: 20
    };

    if (value != $('#ConfirmPassword').val()) {
        this.errorMessage = "Password and Confirm Password should be same";
        this.isValid = false;
    }
    if (value.length < this.options.minLength || value.length > this.options.maxLength) {
        this.errorMessage = "The password must be between 6 and 20 characters long";
        this.isValid = false;
    }
    return this.isValid;
}, this.errorMessage);

$('form').find('input#Password').rules("add", {
     required: true,
     arePasswordsValid: true
});
```

The above doesn't work as `this.errorMessage` isn't accessible, the form validates as far as required fields need to be completed.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to have different rules for each condition

Comment: I had them separate originally, but it would say the passwords didnt match even before it validated the length to say it wasnt long enough

Comment: Why not use the `equalTo` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Your `minlength` and `maxlength` rules are spelled wrong.  Note that the upper-case `L` is incorrect.

2)  The `minlength` and `maxlength` rules can simply be combined into [the `rangelength` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rangelength-method/).

```
rangelength: [6,20]
```

3)  You are making this infinitely more complicated than it needs to be.  Just use [the `equalTo` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalto-method/).  Yours is the exact scenario it was designed to solve.

4)  Use the `messages` option to change the exact wording of any of the messages.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7pN8A/2/**

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        Password: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [6,20]
        },
        ConfirmPassword: {
            equalTo: "#Password"  // this is all you need... the rules for the other will apply
        }
    },
    messages: {  // optional, over-ride default messages
        Password: {
            rangelength: "The password must be between {0} and {1} characters long"
        },
        ConfirmPassword: {
            equalTo: "Password and Confirm Password should be same"
        }
    }
});
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">     
    <input type="password" class="required" name="Password" id="Password">
    <input type="password" class="required" name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to make a more general approach. Instead of directly outputting the message. You can split the validation and the message sending by saving all Infomations first. This way, even complex situations shouldn't be a problem.